# Problem in import/installing python modules (pyserial) in ubuntu 15

Tags: python, serial-port

Hi I've got problems importing `pyserial` in both python 2.7 and 3.5
I've tried with `pip install`, `easy_install`,  deb package, source balls. But always the same :

```
>>> import serial
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named serial
>>>
```

Could you help me, please

Comment: Are you sure it is installed on your system? How did you install it?

Comment: run this command: `pip list | grep pyserial` see if it return anything. if so, share it here

Answer (score 2):

You should install the packages `python-serial` and `python3-serial` using the `apt` package manager:

```
sudo apt-get install python-serial python3-serial
```

Now you can import the module from both Python 2 and 3 with the name `serial`:

```
python -c "import serial; print(serial.__file__)"
python3 -c "import serial; print(serial.__file__)"
```

If those two example commands show you the file where the `serial` module is located, it works correctly.